# google webfonts are not displaying at all - chrome latest version, mac

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I have google fonts on my page for a long time, but recently they started to disappear **only** in **Google Chrome, version 33.0.1750.117, Mac**.. Some of the text with fonts is not displayed, if I click or hover the font displays just fine.

I found only this post about bug in Google Chrome 32, but it should be fixed as it is said, maybe another bug was produced?

http://blog.typekit.com/2014/02/04/chrome-bug-affecting-web-fonts/

Does somebody know about this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am experiencing the same issue, and I have found this discussion.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Following workaround works for me:

```
body
{
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix{
    from{   opacity: 1; }
    to{ opacity: 1; }
}
```

Hope this helps you out as well!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Can you describe what you are trying to do within that fix? When should I load that css?

Comment: @adosaiguas just put it in your main css file

Comment: @Kosmetika :) That's what I did, but it still does not work for me.

Comment: try putting it at the end of your css file.

Comment: I got a bug in this fix. Suppose you have several tabs opened in your browser. While loading the page, if you go to another tab, then return to the previous tab/page after complete loading, this fix will not work.

Answer (score 3):

This workaround also works:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){jQuery('body').width(jQuery('body').width()+1).width('auto')})
```

All credits to post #30 at Chrome's issues discussion forum. Can be found [at here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476#c30)

Answer (score 0):

If you're in need of a Wordpress plugin for this issue, I created one based on the answer of Douglas Tropiano. It can be downloaded here:

http://www.apertoso.be/google-webfonts-niet-zichtbaar-in-google-chrome/

Blogpost in Dutch, download link at the bottom, called "Apertoso – Really simple Google Chrome WebFonts Fix"