# Custom fonts or css loads too late

Tags: css, font-face

My CSS includes custom fonts such as:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'AllerRegular';
  src: url("http://domain/css/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.eot");
  src: url('http://domain/css/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://domain/css/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('http://domain/css/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('http://domain/css/fonts/aller_rg-webfont.svg#AllerRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: AllerRegular, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

When loading the web page, several of the paragraphs *sometimes* seem to be "missing". In the Inspector, I then look at the body, uncheck the line that says `font-family: AllerRegular, sans-serif;`, then check it again. The text comes back!

Because of this test, I am assuming there is some issue in the order that the CSS and the fonts file are loaded.

Also note that the CSS file and the font files are not hosted on the same server.

[image]
[image]

Comment: in every browser? + did you include the CSS in the head?

Comment: My tests are happening in Chrome. Yes CSS is in head.

Comment: if you are using webkit like safari or chrome, this article might be help your font issues: [Fighting the @font-face FOUT](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/)

Comment: Interesting link. The thing it doesn't flash, when it happens, it just doesn't show the text at all unless I manually do something with the text to re-render it.

Comment: I'll go ahead and give the link: http://www.alyah.fr - you may stumble upon it as well.

Comment: This is a Chrome bug. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053010/google-webfonts-are-not-displaying-at-all-chrome-latest-version-mac

Comment: @Iqbal this sounds very similar indeed. Should we merge the question?

Comment: @NathanH You can do that.